# how to fix createsuper error invloving a post save signal

Tags: python, django

Am trying to create a superuser for my new django project, it involves a post save signal that creates user dashboard and save user phone number from the POST request, i define a get_phonenumber() function that returns phonenumber to the signals.py where the function is called. the code work pretty fine when creating a normal user from the browser but when it comes to creating a superuser i have this error (Phone_number not define)

i have try to use if statement to check

```
if phone_number:  
     return phone_number
 else:  
    return "some random string"
```

just to keep a default phonenumber for supperuser, but still getting same error

#### returns phone number to signal.py where the function is called##

```
def get_phone_number():  
    global PHONE_NUMBER  
    return PHONE_NUMBER
```

########### End Gets And return Phone Number ##################

Comment: Better to add code in the question ,not in comments

Comment: you need to show us all the code of your `post_save` signal handler. Also paste the full stack trace of the error. And please use the code formatting option of SO.